# Fungus cross infection

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, diseases, pests

My Dendrobium Nobile Apollon has fungus ...

Is it possible that this fungus could infect other plants like my Hoyas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the possibility is always there. Generally it is a good approach to isolate infected plants from the rest let it be insects or fungus.

You cannot really do harm with isolation given you have a place to put the plant away while giving it acceptable conditions. But if you keep them close/together the risk will be there and even if it is small, I personally do not think it is worth to take.

Comment: So a fungus that mainly targets orchids can also infect other plants that are not orchids if they are in close proximity for a prolonged time. Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: @MysteriousChallenger Given the "right" conditions, any plant can have fungal infections. I had *Monstera deliciosa* for example with a very bad fungal problem which I am sure could have spread to Pothos or *Philodendron*. I am not an expert of different fungus vs. plants so what I say is that I would not risk it. Better to stay on the safe side than learn the hard way. :)

Comment: Alright, yes I do agree with that. I've removed the plant and isolated it. Thanks for the advice!